# How can I set up maven in my office system without proxy details?

Tags: java, maven, proxy

Company's IS team will not provide the proxy details to us explicitly. I am using jdk 1.8 on Windows 7, have several versions of Eclispe, the one I am trying with is Luna. Please suggest.

Comment: If you don't get the proxy settings. Why you want to circumvent this restriction? If there is a business need for you to set up maven in the office someone in your company should be able to help you.

Comment: If you want to use Maven with MavenCentral, you need to be able to connect to the "outside world". If you only use Maven for internal development, you can set up your own Repository.

Comment: I have been trying to get it done by process, it's getting delayed due to some reasons which are hard to explain. But one question, if I take the source code and build it in my home system using maven, will it make a difference during deployment? Are there some factors that I should look out for?

Comment: This issue seems related to your IT admins, due to, I think, some security reason. Please ask them to overcome the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.. got it resolved, there is indeed a separate repository/artifactory supported by my client. I had to create a password based on my single sign on and enter those details in settings.xml. And that did it. 
Just so you all know, I was working on this simultaneously,but asked the question here to see if there is any other possible option. -1 on my question was bit demotivating, but thanks for your responses. Appreciate it!!!